# Regarding localisation language

Tags: android, locale

I am stuck at two things.

1. I need to convert my android app from English to two other languages(let's say Urdu and Telugu).
2. And also convert the data which is coming from backend. Sometimes I get the Urdu language from backend and show it in the same language in my app also but my app is showing QUESTION MARKS.

so for 1: is there any library I can use to convert the whole application into another language by a single click or creating strings.xml for all languages only the solution?

for 2: How to show the backend data into the desired language from the app?

someone, please help

Answer (score 0):

1. **StackOverflow**: [Change app language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android)

**Article**: https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

---

2. You should write your own resource manager if you want to translate the app from the backend server.

Comment: for 1: all the examples showing to write in each activity. but couldn't find any solution for writing one code for whole application.  And can you show me sample how to create resource manager?

Comment: It's Russian, but hope you'll understand google translate https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/346458/         https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/348350/